# Can I make a compiler warn me if I leave an optional argument as its default value?

Tags: c++

I made my own class in C++. I want that the class constructor can work with a default value of an optional argument, but the compiler should warn me that I didn't specify the optional argument. Is there a way to do this? I'm using g++, so it's okay if the solution only works in gcc.

I think `__attribute__` can do what I want, but I couldn't find how.

I want to do this:

```
class somestringclass{
private:
   /* ... */

public:
    somestringclass(char *x, int length = -1) {
        if (length==-1)
        {
            //calculate length by finding '\0' in x,
            //but I want to be warned to avoid potential memory issue by getting char array without '\0'.
        }

        /* some constructing here.. */
    }

    /* some other features here.. */
};
```

Comment: This smells funny. Why do you need the compiler to issue a warning for this?

Comment: If you want to always specify the optional argument, why is it optional?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious because the class is about string(not stl string but char array) and I want it works safely... maybe making it not optional is better?

Comment: The correct thing to do here is show your class definition and we'll explain why you're going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Please show a [mre], the question is unclear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry for the unclearness. (for all people above. It seems that I can only mention one at a time) I edited the question.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I would have two constructors, one that takes a `const char*` and requires a 0 terminated string, and one that takes a `const char*` and a `size_t` for length.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I provided that solution as you posted that and AFAIK it's a far better option than issuing a warning about the usage of that argument. It's always possible (and a strong use-case) to provide a non-null terminated string such as a substring from a `char` buffer as the argument to the string class and a length parameter is necessary to support that.

Comment: You're misusing default values.   If you want a diagnostic when the programmer doesn't provide that argument, then overload the function - (1)  one overload that does NOT accept the argument and is a `private` member of the class.  (2)  A `public` overload that accepts the argument, but does not give it a default value. For (non-member, non-friend) callers not providing the value resolve to the `private` overload, producing a diagnosable error.  Providing the value will call the `public` version.  It may also be preferable to declare but not define the `private` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current class definition and your expectations for the constructor I suggest that you split it into two different constructors - one for each use-case. The first constructor takes only a `const char*` as the argument and the length of the string is determined by searching for a null terminator. The second constructor is similar to the one you have now except the length parameter is not defaulted (i.e. optional). When doing so I also suggest making the `length` parameter an unsigned type (i.e. `size_t`) since there can never be a string with a negative length (this applies to anything with a length or taking an index value). This way you can optionally check for a length of 0 and either throw an exception or assume that it is an empty string.

```
class somestringclass
{
private:
    /* ... */

public:
    somestringclass(const char *x)
    {
        // Calculate length of string by searching for null terminator
    }

    somestringclass(const char *x, size_t length)
    {
        // Check length for 0 if that is not supported or assume empty
    }
};
```

A good use case for having the second constructor that takes a length is the ability to create a string from either a character buffer that may not be null terminated or from only a portion of another string (a substring). This provides a greater amount of usability in your string class. For reference I suggest you look at the [constructors of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) and think about the different ways you might use them to create a string.

This should give you a greater sense of reliability and clarity in the usage of your string type.

Note that I've changed the `char*` pointer argument to `const` to allow passing string literals to the constructor.

Comment: This won't handle the situation where an array without a terminating nul is passed to the first constructor.  Unfortunately, there is no robust solution to that.

Comment: @Peter Correct. There's no way to appropriately handle that situation unless you specify some maximum bounds to the length check. This is why having additional constructores that support the use-case of non-null terminated strings is common and desirable.